# mod_rewrtie remap and redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

what i am trying to do is this:

If url http://example.com/foo/foo.php is called it should be redirected with 301 to http://example.com/bar/foo.php

AND

if url http://example.com/bar/foo.php is called it internally calles the /bar/foo.php script but browser url is not changed (remap).

my rules look like this

```
RewriteRule ^foo/foo.php(.*) bar/foo.php$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^bar/foo.php(.*)$ foo/foo.php$1 [PT]
```

But this gives me too many redirects error.

Each rule activated separately works but together they seem to conflict...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either match against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /foo/foo.php
RewriteRule ^foo/foo.php(.*) bar/foo.php$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^bar/foo.php(.*)$ foo/foo.php$1 [L]
```

Or prevent rewrite looping altogether:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^foo/foo.php(.*) bar/foo.php$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^bar/foo.php(.*)$ foo/foo.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: oops i mean bar/foo.php just didnt rename it before posting. i edited it now. I'll try your suggestion and tell you if it works.